# Exporting a snapshot in KVM to create a clone ala Hyper-V 2008

Tags: hyper-v, kvm-virtualization, clone

Hyper-V has a nice feature of allowing a snapshot of a VM to be exported, meaning a new VM is created with the state of that snapshot.  How can the same be accomplished in KVM ?  Qcow2 images on CentOS 6.3 libvirt 0.10?

Answer (score 1):

1. Take snapshot
2. `qemu-img convert` from the snapshot into a new image
3. create a VM on top of the new image (I'd also sysprep/sys-unconfig it beforehand, to avoid IP/MAC conflicts)

Comment: Could you be a little more specific please?  I assume you are talking about external snapshots, not internal.  Could you show me the actual commands you would recommend?

Comment: I'm not in front of a KVM enabled system at the moment unfortunately, so I can't provide exact commands. You can take snapshots of a running VM using `virsh` on fresh libvirt versions. The technique would beto take the first snapshot (Vm gets switched over to the new snap1), take another snapshot (snap2 - the VM is now running on this one), and now you can use qemu to create a new image based on snap1, without interrupting the running VM, which is using snap2.